# flow of execution of javascript(synchronous or asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

Can someone explain me the behaviour of following code and javascript

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.write('Iteration ' + i + ' <br>');
    },1000);
}

document.write('DONE!');
```

why does it print 'DONE!' first?
Shouldn't it print all values of the loop and then print 'DONE!'?

Comment: 'DONE!' is being printed after `for-loop` is completed..

Comment: [WindowTimers.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: The flow is that you set 5 timeout functions first, then print done - that's done in sequence. The functions execute after interval, that's why done is printed first, but the flow of the program is that first action is setting 5 timeout callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why does it print 'DONE!' first? Shouldn't it print all values of the loop and then print 'DONE!'?

No, you've explicitly told it not to; instead, you've just created five functions and called `setTimeout` five times to give them to the browser to call later.

This code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
document.write('Iteration ' + i + ' <br>');
},1000);
```

calls the function `setTimeout`, passing in the function you see. That function is **not** called at that time. It's just created. `setTimeout` will call it *later*, as is its job. (And when it does, it will blow away the document, because calling `document.write` after the main parsing of the page is complete implicitly does `document.open`, which wipes out the previous document.)

So here's what happens with that code:

1. The variable `i` is created.
2. It's set to `0`.
3. A function is created.
4. `setTimeout` is called with that function object's reference being passed in, along with the value `1000`.
5. `i` is incremented.
6. Steps 2 through 5 repeat for values `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` of `i`.
7. `document.write` is called with the value `'DONE!'`
8. About a second later, the browser calls the first function created in the loop.
9. That function calls `document.write`, which implicitly does a `document.open`, which blows away the existing document and replaces it with `Iteration 5 <br>` (yes, really 5).
10. The second function created in the loop is run, outputting the message again.
11. The remaining three functions are called, adding the message another three times.

The reason we see `Iteration 5` five times instead of `Iteration 0`, then `Iteration 1`, etc., is that the functions have an enduring reference to the *variable* `i`, not to its value when they were created, so they all read its value later, as of when they run.

Comment: Please refer this thread and check answer2:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523870/is-javascript-synchronousblocking-or-asynchronousnonblocking-by-default

Comment: @ProblemSolver: Not sure what you're trying to say there, but note that not everyone sees answers in the same order. If you want to refer to a specific answer, use the "share" link under it to get a link to that specific answer. But I'm not seeing relevant anything there which isn't covered above.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in normal is `Synchronous` Exectue line by line, but with code change you can act sometime as Asynchronous, but it's not actually going to execute on a separate thread.

Ok, what if you want to print `Done` just after the Document.write is done

```
length = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  setTimeout(function(index){
  console.log('Iteration ' + index + ' <br>');
  length++;
  callback();
  }(i),1000);
}

function callback(){
 if(length == 5)
   console.log('DONE!');
}
```

What we did here is we increment the counter and try to call the callback after each time its incremented and when counter reach 5 that mean all the 5 functions is called and then we are able to print `Done`.

And as a side and important note, you was trying to print 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 but actually when you run your code it will give you 5, 5, 5, ,5, 5 because you write `i` and `i` at the point when you print is reached 5 and that's why it go out of the for loop, but you notice the code i added, i pass `i` as an argument to the function so that it will save the value for us and when time to execute the funtion it will write 0, 1, 2, 3, 4